# How should I specify a minimum version of Ember.js in my ember-cli addon?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-cli-addons

I've just published [an ember-cli addon](https://github.com/gabrielgrant/ember-cli-test-model-waiter) using features available only in projects that have [updated to Ember 2.x by making the required changes](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/4671#issuecomment-145947330) to their [`package.json`](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/blob/master/blueprints/app/files/package.json) and [`bower.json`](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/blob/master/blueprints/app/files/bower.json).

How should I specify that the addon will only work with Ember 2.x?

Answer (score 0):

Very late answer, but I found this question while searching for this myself.

The answer is to require [ember-cli-version-checker](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli-version-checker). The documentation gives several examples, but to require a minimum version of Ember itself you would do

```js
//index.js
let VersionChecker = require('ember-cli-version-checker');

module.exports = {
  name: 'awesome-addon',
  init() {
    let checker = new VersionChecker(this);

    checker.for('ember-cli').assertAbove('2.0.0', 'To use awesome-addon you must have ember-cli 2.0.0');
  }
};
```